# flot charts: change the axis data type to time

Tags: javascript, html, flot

I want my chart's X axis data type as time: minute and seconds. [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) is  a doc, but it is difficult for me to find how to apply in `$.plot(placeholder, data, options)` . As the above doc mentions, it does the formatting itself and we need only give it the javascript time (long value) . Any one let me explain with an example how I can change my X axis data type as time and format it ?

I have put my code into [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/deborad/q4qakg4g/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this as part of your `options` object to show minutes and seconds:

```
var options = {
    ...
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%M:%S"
    }
    ...
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) is the part of the documentation which descibes the options for time series.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that with including the `jquery.flot.time.js` file. It gives error in cosole, juery flot time plugin is required. But I have already added that. I have set the time values in series (new Date().getTime() as javascript time value.) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I added my code in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/deborad/q4qakg4g/. I got a sample code from flotjs documentation and changed as I needed. (Sorry for my delay to reply.I was struggling with some other parts of my app.So it was delayed.but don't assume, I don't care much)